# is it possible to standard datetime in Python3 from different format of string input

Tags: python

I am now need to parse string into datetime in Python3, this is my code:

```
parse_time = time.strptime(pub_time, '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
formatted_timestamp = time.mktime(parse_time)
```

now I encount an error:

```
time data '2020-08-02T08:58:01.000Z' does not match format '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'
```

and now what should I do to fix it? then my `pub_time` maybe have differnt format parsing from internet, what should I do to make it auto suite with different format. The best is auto detect different type of time format and standard it to one way.

Because I really did not know which format the web content will return. if It could automatic detect the format and convert, so I did not need write any mapping or dectect code.

Answer (score 0):

using [maya](https://pypi.org/project/maya/) lib may help:

```
import maya

date_array = [
    '2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860',
    'Jun 28 2018 7:40AM',
    'Jun 28 2018 at 7:40AM',
    'September 18, 2017, 22:19:55',
    'Sun, 05/12/1999, 12:30PM',
    'Mon, 21 March, 2015',
    '2018-03-12T10:12:45Z',
    '2018-06-29 17:08:00.586525+00:00',
    '2018-06-29 17:08:00.586525+05:00',
    'Tuesday , 6th September, 2017 at 4:30pm'
]

for date in date_array:
    print('Parsing: ' + date)
    dt = maya.parse(date).datetime()
    print(dt)
    print(dt.date())
    print(dt.time())
    print(dt.tzinfo)
```

Comment: When recommending a 3rd-party module, it is customary to include a link to said module.

Comment: today I just find the way to solve this problem, maybe help others if they has the same problem. I asked the same time, I will try to figure out and solve by myself.@PythonMaster202